If $X_n \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} x$; then $\max\{0,X_n\} \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} \max\{0,x \}$

If $X_n \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} x$; then $\max\{0,X_n\} \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} \max\{x,0\}$

I'm looking for the inequality used for proving this; I'd say that:
$$|\max\{0,X_n\}-\max\{x,0\}|=\left| \frac{|X_n|+X_n}{2}-\frac{|x|+x}{2} \right|$$
and
$$\left|\frac{|X_n|+X_n}{2}-\frac{|x|+x}{2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}\big(|X_n-x|+ ||X_n|-|x||\big) \leq \frac{2}{2}|X_n-x|$$
$$P(|\max\{0,X_n\}-\max\{x,0\}| \geq \epsilon) \leq P(|X_n-x| \geq \epsilon) \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{n \to \infty} 0$$

That's one way. More generally, you can use the criterion that $X_n\to Y$ in probability if and only if for all subsequences $\left{X_{n_k}\right}{k\in\Bbb N}$ there is a sub-subsequence $\left{X{n_{k_h}}\right}{h\in\Bbb N}$ such that $X{n_{k_h}}\to Y$ almost surely. This can be used to prove the continuous mapping theorem, i.e. that $X_n\to Y$ in probability and $g$ continuous implies $g(X_n)\to g(Y)$ in probability.

Hint: split the problem in a set $\Omega_1={\omega:X_n(\omega)\leq 0}$ and $\Omega_0={\omega:X_n(\omega)>0}$. In any case, the result follows by the mapping theorem as $f:x\mapsto x\wedge 0$ is continuous.

@Daan $x\lor 0$, but ok.
